# How to display one name in three tables many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have three tables (`student's_info`, `subjects` and `marks`):

This is `student's_info`:

```
----------------
|s_id | s_name |
----------------
| 1   | Liza   |
| 2   | Jake   |
----------------
```

This is `subjects`:

```
------------------
|sub_id | subject|
------------------
| 1   | Word     |
| 2   | Windows  |
| 3   | Excel    |
------------------
```

and this is `marks`:

```
-----------------------------------
|id | s_id |sub_id| n1  | n2 | n3 |
-----------------------------------
| 1 |  1   |  1   |  50 | 20 | 10 |
| 2 |  1   |  2   |  44 | 33 | 23 |
| 3 |  1   |  3   |  90 | 44 | 31 |
| 4 |  2   |  1   |  32 | 12 | 11 |
| 5 |  2   |  2   |  56 | 28 | 32 |
| 6 |  2   |  3   |  66 | 33 | 44 |
-----------------------------------
```

I have this query to select data:

```
SELECT students_info.*, marks.*, subjects.subject
  FROM subjects
         RIGHT JOIN (students_info
                       RIGHT JOIN marks ON students_info.s_id = marks.s_id
                    ) ON subjects.sub_id = marks.sub_id";
```

The query result is:

```
Liza  Word     50 20 10
Liza  Windows  44 33 23
Liza  Excel    90 44 31
Jake  Word     32 12 11
Jake  Windows  56 28 21
Jake  Excel    66 33 44
```

My question is: Why is the sutdent's name repeated? How can I get blank out the student's name if it's the same as in the previous row?

Comment: This is a Display Tier problem not a Database problem.

Comment: Post your expected exit result

Comment: Ok @MichaelKutz the address of my question is error, how i can display one name student with other subject and marks?

Comment: @JesusUzcanga the result appear on above my question.

Comment: Note - the results shown don't match the query shown. You would see `student's_info.s_id`, as well as the three ID columns from `marks` - and, of course, the data for "Jake". It may seem like this is being picky - but it means we aren't seeing the actual query you issued, and thus may be missing something important.

Comment: Thanks @RDFozz for editing i don't speak English very well sorry,
I want to the name student appear only one not for every subject appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior in any database. The value "Liza" shows on each line because it's the value from `student's_info.s_name` for the rows being shown.

You want to suppress the information to improve the presentation of the data (i.e., the way it looks). This is why [Michael Kutz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/145266/michael-kutz) calls it a "Display Tier" problem.

The data being returned from the query is exactly correct; you want to modify it when you go to display it to an end user. Generally, it's recommended that this sort of thing be handled by the application that's going to deliver the data to said end user.

There are ways to manipulate the result set to not display the student's name if it's the same as it was on the previous row, if for some reason you cannot do it in the application. However, they result in a more complicated query.

I've put together a query that seems to work, with the sample data at least. You can see it in action at this [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wae3wCBYeZUzSLkGGBPn3/3). Note that I've tweaked your names slightly (the apostrophe/single quote character is almost always used to mean something in SQL, so I'd avoid it in an object name).

The fiddle shows the results - as you desired, the first row for each student shows their name, and the following rows for the same student leave the name blank.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT s_name_display, sub_name, n1, n2, n3
  FROM (SELECT if(@last_s_name = s_name, '', s_name) as s_name_display
              ,@last_s_name := s_name as name_set_to
              ,sub_name
              ,n1,n2,n3
              ,@row_number := @row_number + 1 as sort_id
          FROM (        
                SELECT student.s_name
                      ,subject.sub_name
                      ,marks.n1, marks.n2, marks.n3
                  FROM subject
                         RIGHT JOIN (student
                                       RIGHT JOIN marks ON student.s_id = marks.s_id
                                    ) ON subject.sub_id = marks.sub_id
                 ORDER BY student.s_name, subject.sub_name
                ) base
       ) sq
 ORDER BY sort_id
;
```

The subquery named `base` is your original query. We sort the data in the desired order here.

The subquery `sq` uses `base` with two variables. One, `@last_s_name`, holds the `s_name` from the previous row. `@row_number` is used to set a row number - we want to be certain that the final output is shown in the same order as what we have here, since row order is critical (the first appearance of each student name *has* to come before the other rows with that student's name).

We determine the name to display by comparing the student name from the previous row with the student name in the current row. If they're the same, we return an empty string as `s_display_name`; otherwise, we return the actual `s_name`.

Finally, we select just the columns we want from the `sq` subquery, and make sure they're sorted correctly in the outermost query.

Like I said - this is *much* more complicated than your original query. For that matter, I can't guarantee that this will scale - merely that it works fine with your sample data.

Comment: Thanks very much @RDFozz ,this is work in DB-Fiddle, but it's difficult write in nootpad++, where is the location codes (SET last_s_name = '';
SET row_number = 0;).

Comment: That's set in the schema pane. `@row_number` is initially set to `0`, `@last_s_name` to `''` (empty string). And I'd probably have found it easier to write in my text editor of choice than on the DB-Fiddle page directly; it's not incredibly easy that way either!

Comment: Thank you @RDFozz, that is a good but one problem to write `SET @last_s_name = '';`  `SET @row_number = 0;` in my notepad syntax error, unexpected '@' –

Comment: May be a discrepancy between Notepad++ and actual MySQL syntax. Check MySQL man pages on variables - I believe you can use them without the @, but I'm not sure what the rules are.

Comment: Mr. @RDFozz I change the @ to the $ sign work for me, but why repeat name student's at the DB Fiddle, open this and see the output, [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wae3wCBYeZUzSLkGGBPn3/1)

Comment: I've updated the DB-Fiddle link in the answer. The "Schema SQL" block and the "Query SQL" block run as different sessions, apparently, so the values of the variables weren't being initialized. (User variables only exist for the duration of a given session). I moved the `SET` commands to the "Query SQL" block, and everything works again. It's possible the DB-Fiddle site itself was updated - I now get a warning when using my work browser to hit it that I wasn't getting before. Anyway, it seems to work as it did when I first posted it with that minor change.